# Loading images using picasso on a slow connection

Tags: android, picasso

I am using Picasso to load images for a listview.
The problem is internet connection is slow.
How can I change load timeout time in Picasso?

My code is :

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(MainActivity.WEBSITE + book_item.Image)
.resize(final_thumb_width, final_thumb_height)
.into(new PicassoTarget(book_item,item.img, item.title));
```

Comment: post some code please.

Comment: @hanaa I don't think code is necessary here.

Comment: Set Connection Time out for HttpUrlConnection

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA But how I change HttpUrlConnection of Picasso?

Answer (score 4):

You could possibly try something like this in your MainActivity's onCreate (or whereever you want to create the Picasso Builder

```
    Picasso picasso;
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

    okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    picasso = new Picasso.Builder(this)
            .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient))
            .build();
```

That should give Picasso a timeout of ten seconds. Configure it to your needs.

Full Disclosure: I don't use a timeout. I just noticed this in the API. This may be completely wrong lol.

Comment: Since Picasso 2.5.0 OkHttpDownloader class has been changed, assuming you are using OkHttp3 (and so picasso2-okhttp3-downloader), so you have to do something like this:

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Subclass a `Downloader` class. [Check this](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso/src/main/java/com/squareup/picasso/OkHttpDownloader.java) for reference implementation
2. Preconfigure OkHttpClient with timeouts and pass it to Picasso

Comment: given link is dead.